# Teradata to Postgres: SQL translation for SET table, NO FALLBACK, NO BEFORE JOURNAL, NO AFTER JOURNAL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, teradata, postgresql-9.4

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SET TABLE SAMPLE
  ,NO FALLBACK
  ,NO BEFORE JOURNAL
  ,NO AFTER JOURNAL
  ,CHECKSUM = DEFAULT
  ,DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
(ACCT_ID VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
,EMP_SAL CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL));
```

How to translate these options in Postgres?

Comment: could you expand the question more clearly?

Comment: You probably don't need to.  Get the code to work without the arcane options.

Comment: @rubadubdub Expanded the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Are you meaning like these characters like latin/case specific will be auto handled by Postgres internally. Also commands like No Fallback, No before can omitted?

Comment: @Karthikk . . . See if it works.  If it doesn't add the appropriate Postgres options.  The parts about journaling and all that affect performance, but not functionality.

Comment: What does this do in Teradata?

Comment: plus 1 you don't need it in PostGres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all the table level options:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SET TABLE SAMPLE -- There'n no OR REPLACE in TD and PG
  ,NO FALLBACK -- keeps a copy of every row, doesn't exist in PG -> remove it
  ,NO BEFORE JOURNAL -- Journalling options
  ,NO AFTER JOURNAL  -- -> remove
  ,CHECKSUM = DEFAULT -- checksumming datablocks to prevent writing/reading bad data -> remove
  ,DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO -- Combine smaller data blocks during Insert/Update/Delete -> remove
(ACCT_ID VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
,EMP_SAL CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL));
```

`CHARACTER SET LATIN`: afaik there's no option in PG to specify a character set on a column level, only on database level.

`NOT CASESPECIFIC`: specifying case sensitivity for a CHAR column doesn't exists in PG (it's always case sensitive), there's only a [citext module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/citext.html).

Comment: great, thanks for the update. I will try and let you know.